# CallNtPowerInformation function fails, and the return value is STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL

Tags: c++, winapi

Here is my code, I find the values of the a never change, then I check the return value, and it is STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>  
extern "C" {
#include <Powrprof.h>
}
#pragma comment(lib, "Powrprof.lib")
typedef struct _PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION {
    ULONG  Number;
    ULONG  MaxMhz;
    ULONG  CurrentMhz;
    ULONG  MhzLimit;
    ULONG  MaxIdleState;
    ULONG  CurrentIdleState;
} PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION, *PPROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION a;
    while (1)
    {
        CallNtPowerInformation(ProcessorInformation, NULL, 0, &a, sizeof(a));       
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The OutputBufferSize is sizeof(a), but why it returns STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL, and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372675.aspx)? *"ProcessorInformation: The lpOutputBuffer buffer receives one [PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373184.aspx) structure **for each processor that is installed on the system**. Use the [GetSystemInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381.aspx) function to retrieve the number of processors."*

Comment: @IInspectable you missed the answer box :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [`CallNtPowerInformation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372675.aspx) documentation:

> ProcessorInformation
>   11
>
> The `lpInBuffer` parameter must be NULL; otherwise the function returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.
>
> **The `lpOutputBuffer` buffer receives one [`PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373184.aspx) structure for each processor that is installed on the system. Use the [`GetSystemInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381.aspx) function to retrieve the number of processors.**

Your buffer is too small because you are allocating only 1 [`PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373184.aspx) total, not 1 for each installed processor.  It is very rare nowadays that a PC only has 1 processor installed.  Multi-core and hyper-threaded CPUs present multiple processors to the OS.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>  

extern "C" {
#include <Powrprof.h>
}

#include <vector>

#pragma comment(lib, "Powrprof.lib")

typedef struct _PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION {
    ULONG  Number;
    ULONG  MaxMhz;
    ULONG  CurrentMhz;
    ULONG  MhzLimit;
    ULONG  MaxIdleState;
    ULONG  CurrentIdleState;
} PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION, *PPROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SYSTEM_INFO si = {0};
    GetSystemInfo(&si);

    std::vector<PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION> a(si.dwNumberOfProcessors);
    DWORD dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION) * si.dwNumberOfProcessors;

    do
    {
        CallNtPowerInformation(ProcessorInformation, NULL, 0, &a[0], dwSize);
    }
    while (true);

    a.clear();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Note the following caveat in the [`SYSTEM_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724958.aspx) documentation:

> dwNumberOfProcessors
>   The number of logical processors **in the current group**. To retrieve this value, use the [`GetLogicalProcessorInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683194.aspx) function.

32-bit systems only support 64 logical processors max.  64bit systems support more processors via [Processor Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405503.aspx).

If your PC has 64 or fewer logical processors installed, the above code will work fine.  However, if your PC has more than 64 logical processors installed, use [`GetActiveProcessorCount()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getactiveprocessorcount) or [`GetLogicalProcessorInformation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683194.aspx) to determine the total number of logical processors installed.

The below code is tweaked from the example provided in the [`GetLogicalProcessorInformation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683194.aspx) documentation:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>  

extern "C" {
#include <Powrprof.h>
}

#include <vector>

#pragma comment(lib, "Powrprof.lib")

typedef struct _PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION {
    ULONG  Number;
    ULONG  MaxMhz;
    ULONG  CurrentMhz;
    ULONG  MhzLimit;
    ULONG  MaxIdleState;
    ULONG  CurrentIdleState;
} PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION, *PPROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION;

typedef BOOL (WINAPI *LPFN_GLPI)(PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION, PDWORD);
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *LPFN_GLPIEX)(LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_RELATIONSHIP, PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX, PDWORD);
typedef DWORD (WINAPI *LPFN_GAPC)(WORD);

#define ALL_PROCESSOR_GROUPS 0xffff

// Helper function to count set bits in the processor mask.
DWORD CountSetBits(ULONG_PTR bitMask)
{
    DWORD LSHIFT = sizeof(ULONG_PTR)*8 - 1;
    DWORD bitSetCount = 0;
    ULONG_PTR bitTest = (ULONG_PTR)1 << LSHIFT;    
    DWORD i;

    for (i = 0; i <= LSHIFT; ++i)
    {
        bitSetCount += ((bitMask & bitTest)?1:0);
        bitTest/=2;
    }

    return bitSetCount;
}

DWORD GetInstalledProcessorCount()
{
    // on Windows 7 and later, use GetActiveProcessorCount() ...

    LPFN_GAPC gapc = (LPFN_GAPC) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")), "GetActiveProcessorCount");
    if (gapc)
        return gapc(ALL_PROCESSOR_GROUPS);

    // on Vista and later, try GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx() next ...

    LPFN_GLPIEX glpiex = (LPFN_GLPIEX) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")), "GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx");
    if (glpiex) 
    {
        std::vector<BYTE> buffer;
        PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX info = NULL;
        DWORD bufsize = 0;

        // not using RelationGroup because it does not return accurate info under WOW64...
        while (!glpiex(RelationProcessorCore, info, &bufsize))
        {
            if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
                return 0;

            buffer.resize(bufsize);
            info = (PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX) &buffer[0];
        } 

        DWORD logicalProcessorCount = 0;

        while (bufsize >= sizeof(SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX))
        {
            // for RelationProcessorCore, info->Processor.GroupCount is always 1...
            logicalProcessorCount += CountSetBits(info->Processor.GroupMask[0].Mask);
            bufsize -= info->Size;
            info = (PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX) ((LPBYTE)info) + info->Size);
        }

        return logicalProcessorCount;
    }

    // on XP and later, try GetLogicalProcessorInformation() next...

    LPFN_GLPI glpi = (LPFN_GLPI) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")), "GetLogicalProcessorInformation");
    if (glpi) 
    {
        std::vector<BYTE> buffer;
        PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION info = NULL;
        DWORD bufsize = 0;

        while (!glpi(info, &bufsize))
        {
            if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
                return 0;

            buffer.resize(bufsize);
            info = (PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION) &buffer[0];
        } 

        DWORD logicalProcessorCount = 0;

        while (bufsize >= sizeof(SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION))
        {
            if (info->Relationship == RelationProcessorCore)
            {
                // A hyperthreaded core supplies more than one logical processor.
                logicalProcessorCount += CountSetBits(info->ProcessorMask);
            }

            bufsize -= sizeof(SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION);
            ++info;
        }

        return logicalProcessorCount;
    }

    // fallback to GetSystemInfo() last ...

    SYSTEM_INFO si = {0};
    GetSystemInfo(&si);

    return si.dwNumberOfProcessors;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    DWORD dwNumProcessors = GetInstalledProcessorCount();

    std::vector<PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION> a(dwNumProcessors);
    DWORD dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION) * dwNumProcessors;

    while (CallNtPowerInformation(ProcessorInformation, NULL, 0, &a[0], dwSize) == STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        // use data in `a` as needed...
    }

    a.clear();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

According to @DanielWiddis in comments, `CallNtProcessInformation()` returns power info only for the calling thread's current Processor Group.  So, if your PC has more than 64 logical processors installed, you can call `CallNtProcessInformation()` in a loop, changing the calling thread's current process group via [`SetThreadGroupAffinity()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405516.aspx) as needed on each iteration, per [this discussion](https://community.osr.com/discussion/265659/) that I found online.  To determine which Processor Groups are present and how many logical processors belong to each group, use [`GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getlogicalprocessorinformationex), or [`GetActiveProcessorGroupCount()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getactiveprocessorgroupcount) and [`GetActiveProcessorCount()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getactiveprocessorcount).

Comment: While you correctly point out that `SYSTEM_INFO` only counts processors in the current group, your suggestion to use `GetLogicalProcessorInformation()` suffers the same flaw.  Even your bit counting function is only summing up bits in a (max 64 bit) LONG.   You need to use [GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getlogicalprocessorinformationex) to get all the groups.

Comment: Also, after testing on a system with 80 logical processors on it, the second part of your answer is irrelevant. `CallNtPowerInformation()` only returns values for logical processors on the current processor group, as counted by `GetSystemInfo()`.

Comment: @DanielWiddis the code I presented loops through the installed processor cores and sums up the total processor bits for all cores. So yes, the bit counting function only counts up to 64 bits, but that function is called for each core that is present (maybe you only saw `=` where I actually use `+=`?). In an case, this counting logic is not MY code, but is a tweaked version of the example present in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getlogicalprocessorinformation).

Comment: @DanielWiddis I updated my answer to address the `CallNtPowerInformation()` limitation when multiple processor groups are present.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer! The point I was trying to make was that `si.dwNumberOfProcessors` will give you an identical number  to summing up the bits from `GetLogicalProcessorInformation`. Without the `Ex` your original answer still only returned the current processor group.  However, I did fail to note that you were doing that because the docs told you to! I don't quite understand why it says to go somewhere else to get a value already present in the structure! In any case, your edited answer is accurate about the need to iterate over processor groups and set affinity.

Comment: @DanielWiddis yes, I do now see the following note in the `GetLogicalProcessorInformation` documentation: "*On systems with more than 64 logical processors, the GetLogicalProcessorInformation function retrieves logical processor information about processors in the processor group to which the calling thread is currently assigned. Use the GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx function to retrieve information about processors in all processor groups on the system.*"